# Cannot update PopOS

Tags: upgrade, pop-os

I am trying to upgrade PopOS through the PopShop.

When I click the upgrade button I get the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libqt5svg5: Depends: libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg~) but it is not going to be installed
  libegl1: Depends: libegl-mesa0 but it is not going to be installed
  libmutter-7-0: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.32-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libgl1 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libx11-xcb1 (>= 2:1.7.0) but 2:1.6.12-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
  systemd-sysv: Depends: systemd (= 247.3-3ubuntu3.4pop0~1626806865~21.04~19f7a6d)
  fwupd: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.32-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
         Depends: libfwupdplugin1 (>= 1.5.8-0ubuntu1pop0~1617221312~21.04~a9de48d) but 1.5.8-0ubuntu1pop0~1617221312~20.10~a9de48d is to be installed
         Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.7.0) but 3.6.15-4ubuntu2 is to be installed
         Depends: libgusb2 (>= 0.3.5) but 0.3.4-0.2 is to be installed
         Depends: libtss2-esys-3.0.2-0 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not installable
  linux-headers-5.11.0-7620-generic: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33) but 2.32-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
  gnome-terminal: Depends: libvte-2.91-0 (>= 0.62.1) but 0.62.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                  Recommends: yelp but it is not going to be installed
```

When I try to install the first missing package it seems to be installed

```
08:53:22 jphamlett@pop-os Freelance → sudo apt-get install libqt5widgets5
[sudo] password for jphamlett: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt5widgets5 is already the newest version (5.14.2+dfsg-6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.
```

Even just a simple apt-get -f install did nothing

Any help?

Comment: So if you try to install `libqt5svg5` which depends on `libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.14.2+dfsg~)` then it should work (or reveal another unmet dependency). Have to say that the `Depends: libc6 (>= 2.33)` is going to cause lots of problems, since very many packages have libc6 dependencies. Can't advise you about POP, but for many distros, you'd ask is a reinstall of the system a possibility?